# Linux running very slow in virtual box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

**What I am trying to do ?**

I have downloaded Linux lite and Linux mint iso files and I want to run them on virtual box.

**What is the problem ?**

It takes ages to run both the operating systems even though my pc meets the system requirements for running virtual box.

**What I have tried:**

• Enabling 3D Acceleration in virtual box.

• Set video memory to max (128MB).

• Ended all other background processes.

**My Pc Config:**

Motherboard : Mercury Pi945gcm.

Cpu : core2duo 2.0ghz

Ram : 2gb DDR2

Harddisk : 500gb

Os : Windows 7 32bit.

And in the task manager is can see the load on my cpu is 100% when I am running the Linux on virtual box. Does that mean I can't run virtual box with this cpu ? The only option I can think of is overlocking. Would that help in running virtual box smoothly ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the host OS, which you don’t mention, running a reasonably-sized VM (512 MB RAM max) might be feasible. However, hard disks aren’t all that great with VMs.

Comment: Edit the question take a look. Its windows 7.

Comment: And I have assigned 1gig of ram to Linux.

Comment: Check your BIOS for virtualization options (one could be called VT-x) and enable them if they aren't.

Comment: @xenoid  Guess what My processor does not support VT-x https://ark.intel.com/products/29753/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E4400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: Then you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meeting the minimum requirements means just that, bare minimum.
It will run... but only just.

You really don't have either the processor, RAM or HD to be running VMs at anything like full speed.

Comment: Would overclocking my cpu help ?

Comment: Not in the slightest. You have an old machine that was pretty much bottom-spec when new.

Comment: I just used Ubuntu and guess what the cpu usage gets 100% only in Linux lite. But all of them are very slow.

Comment: Can I not dual boot ? That way Linux would get all the resources. And then it would not be slow.

Comment: That would be an entirely different question. You still have an old, slow machine, nothing is going to run quickly on it.

Comment: How is it gonna be slow in dual boot ? It's following the recommended requirements. 2gb for windows ( My machine is working perfectly fine with 2gb ) and for Linux it would be much better.

Comment: I think older versions of Linux would not be slow.

Answer (score 1):

2GB of RAM is a bare minimum for Windows. By allocating half of it to the VM you are effectively starving Windows of RAM.

Windows is probably fighting the VM for RAM and variously paging parts of the VM memory out to disk and then having to page it back in again.

Out of preference you need a minimum of 2GB of RAM for Windows and then *extra* RAM for other tasks. If you want to run a VM with 1GB then you should have 3GB or more in your system. From experience a 945 based motherboard will be limited to 4GB max.

Your processor might be slow, but it should work.

Comment: No my motherboard only supports 2gb max. And 1gb is minimum requirements not 2gb for windows 7.

Comment: Minimum yes. Comfortable or usable? Not really. Definitely not with the extra overheads of 128MB for graphics and whatever else Virtualbox needs. With 1GB (Linux) +  128MB(VB Graphics) + 100MB (conservative estimate for Virtualbox) you are leaving Windows  with less than 800MB. If you are using integrated graphics on your motherboard then that would probably reduce it to less than 700MB. You cannot *comfortably* run Windows and Virtualbox with that little RAM. Either reduce the RAM allocated to Virtualbox or get a system with more RAM.

Comment: Windows works fine even if I am running Linux in virtual box. Only the Linux is been slow not the windows. And I reduced the ram allocated to Linux to 512MB but still the same problem. Should I run the older version of Linux ? That would have less ram requirement.